# what is the limit of concurrent put requests for one table in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) it says that:

> CreateTable/UpdateTable/DeleteTable
> In general, you can have up to 50 CreateTable, UpdateTable, and DeleteTable requests running simultaneously (in any combination). In
> other words, the total number of tables in the CREATING, UPDATING, or
> DELETING state cannot exceed 50.
>
> ```
> The only exception is when you are creating a table with one or more secondary indexes. You can have up to 25 such requests running at
> ```
>
> a time. However, if the table or index specifications are complex,
> DynamoDB might temporarily reduce the number of concurrent operations.
>
> BatchGetItem A single BatchGetItem operation can retrieve a maximum of
> 100 items. The total size of all the items retrieved cannot exceed 16
> MB.

So I want to know if this means that I've only 25 request per table or this is just the case when I use BatchGetItem

Comment: These limits only apply when modifying a table structure, not for putting, getting, deleting, doing anything with the items and contents. Those requests are basically limitless. The last limit is something different but your question still does not make sense in its context.

Comment: One write capacity unit = one write per second - max. 40,000 write request units by default (but changeable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relevant limit on the **rate** of `PutItem` API call itself.

The limits that play a part stem from the write capacity units (WCUs) on your table.
As long as you have enough write throughput (i.e. WCUs) available, `PutItem` will work.

You decide how many WCUs you provision for your table via provisioned throughput or on-demand capacity.

Each WCU allows you to write 1KB per second to the table.
Unused WCUs are also buffered for up to 5 minutes, so you can burst a little.

If you go past your WCUs, you'll get a `ProvisionedThroughputExceeded` error, which is not a rate-limit, but the aforementioned throughput limit.

Comment: I think this means If I've on-demand capacity then I've theoretically unlimited calls

Comment: Theoretically yes, practically no - even with on-demand capacity you can get throttled, if you increase the rate faster than DynamoDB can scale in the background. That happens if you go from basically 0 to a couple thousands WCUs in a few seconds.

Comment: Just realized this is only partially correct, there is a soft-limit on the number of WCUs, which you may need to rise if you want to go beyond 40k as luk2302 mentions in the comments to the question

Comment: in my case 40K is way bigger than our current need, but good to know